# Проблема с парсингом строки в double

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

Столкнулся с проблемой при парсинге текста из строки в тип double. В textbox вводится строка, потом она парсится в double через tryparse (заменяю точки на запятые, чтобы строка успешно запарсилась). Однако, если в textbox ввести число с запятой, то запятая где-то теряется, после чего в textbox и datagrid автоматически подставляется целочисленное число (просто убирается запятая)

Page.xaml.cs

```
bool success = double.TryParse(HeightTBX.Text.Replace('.',',' ), out Height);
bool success1 = double.TryParse(LengthTBX.Text.Replace('.',',' ), out Length);
```

Page.xaml

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Длина_отвала }" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Background="Gray" Width="175" Height="30" 
                 Margin="0 15 0 0"
                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 Name="LengthTBX"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding Высота_отвала}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Background="Gray" Width="175" Height="30" 
                 Margin="0 15 0 0"
                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 Name="HeightTBX"/>
```

[image: Число с точкой корректно вводится и сохраняется]

[image: Ввожу число с запятой]

[image: Переключаюсь на другой textbox - запятая пропала, данные в datagrid изменились]

Comment: У вас 2 проблемы. 1. Вы не используете привязки, ведь если вы создадите сразу например `public double Test {get; set;}` и привяжете ее `<TextBox Text="{Binding Test}"/>`, то сама WPF будет вам автоматически преобразовывать все в нужный тип, без каких-либо костылей, и даже больше скажу, она начнет выделять поле, если там ошибка (запятая/точка наприме). 2. Вы не долждны делать `Replace` строки, а просто должны задать культуру `TryParse`, тогда он сам будет понимать, что там запятая или точка.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо за ответ. Действительно, можно обойтись и без костыля с парсингом, видимо я раньше работал на более старой версии, сейчас прямо под текстбоксами появляется надпись, если введенные данные не соответствуют типу, к которому они привязаны. Другой вопрос - у меня пропадает запятая в текстбоксе и число становится целым, это я не решил, как исправить. Причем пропадает при переключении на другой, т.е без нажатия кнопки сохранить

Comment: Минимальный, воспроизводящий пример кода давайте, чтобы можно было воспроизвести проблему у себя. Ибо если я сейчас сделаю как написал выше, даже если будут страницы, то у меня значение не поменяется.

Comment: Данные подгружаю из БД, поэтому могу предоставить разметки XAML и самого кода. 
Конструктор страницы, параметром принимает выделенную строку datagrid
`public BuldozerEditPage(Бульдозер selectedBuldozer)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ListBuldozers = new ObservableCollection<Бульдозер>();
            GetBuldozers();
            if (selectedBuldozer != null)
            {
                _currentBuldozer = selectedBuldozer;
            }
            DataContext = _currentBuldozer;
        }`

Comment: Разметка textbox
`<TextBox Text="{Binding Длина_отвала}"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Background="Gray" Width="175" Height="30" 
                 Margin="0 15 0 0"
                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 Name="LengthTBX"/>`
Датагрид и два текстбокса привязаны к модели, 
`public Nullable<double> Длина_отвала { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> Высота_отвала { get; set; }`

Comment: В вопрос - кнопка "править" под ним. Данные из базы меняете заглушками, проблем как бы не вижу в этом. Не свой код кидайте, а сделайте пустой, чистый WPF проект, в котором сделайте текстовое поле и внесите в него значение. Получившийся код в вопрос, будем смотреть.